# How do I move files to appropriate folder based on Month and Year?

Tags: vbscript, string-parsing

I have this very complicated requirement.

We have a bunch of zipped files downloaded from an ftp server into a folder in our local directory.

Then we use the code below to unzip the files.

```vb
Set objZip = CreateObject("XStandard.Zip")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\MUSK\FTP\MainFolder\")

For Each fil In fldr.Files
If LCase( Right( fil.Name, 4 ) ) = ".zip" Then
zipFilePath = fil.Path
objZip.UnPack zipFilePath, ("C:\MUSK\FTP\Current\")
End If
Next
```

So far so good.

Here is where problems come in.

These downloaded files have the following naming convention:

filename_month-day-year.zip

Example: Assuming today is May 16, 2012, the filename looks like this:

myFile_5-16-2012.zip

Our requirement is to grab the downloaded zipped files and place them in their correct folder.

For instance, we have folders named according month and year.

Example: We have JAN2012, FEB2012, etc

So taking myFIle_5-16-2012.zip as an example, the myFile_5-16-2012.zip is for MAY2012.

We would like to use the script above to grab the myFile_5-16-2012.zip and place it in the appropriate folder. In this example, the appropriate folder would be MAY2012 and then unzip it.

Basically, the MonthYear folder will replace this:

objZip.UnPack zipFilePath, ("C:\MUSK\FTP\Current\")

In other words, instead of the Current folder, it will be MAY2012 or whatever MonthYear combination.

Is this possible?

I would be more than happy to clarify. Sorry if I confused anyone.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with ASP; it's about string parsing in VBScript. Tags edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes,sorry about that and thanks for changing the tags appropriately.

Comment: The logic is pretty straightforward, if the filenames are like you say. Extract the portion of the filename starting 1 character after `_` and ending 1 character before the `.`, which would be the date portion. Extract the first part up to the first `-`, which is the numeric month, and the last part from the end back to the last `-`, which is the year. Use the numeric month to look up a string month name, combine the two to create your `MonthYear` folder name, and see if it exists. If it doesn't, create it. Append it to the base path, and pass that to your `Unpack` procedure. :)

Comment: I will be eternally grateful for a sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward.  I would:

1. Create a function which converts file name to appropriate MMMYYYY format
2. Use the FileSystemObject to determine if the folder name created in step 1 exists, and create if needed
3. Pass the full directory to your XStandard.Zip object

Check out the supported methods of FileSystemObject here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.85).aspx

You'll need `.FolderExists` and `.CreateFolder`, at least.

---

A quick VBScript I whipped up, could probably use some error checking and whatnot.  Enjoy

```
' parse date, assumes file name is in foo_M-D-YYYY.ext format
Function parseDate(s)
    dim dt
    dt = CDate(split(split(s, "_")(1), ".")(0))
    parseDate = Monthname(Month(dt)) & Year(dt)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It isn't really as straightforward as it may seem to you.

One very important point to bear in mind is that the downloaded zipped folder has date appended to it. As indicated in the my original thread, a typical file has filename and date as in myFile_Month-Day-Year. So, we will need to determine the month and year appended to the filename before we can determine which folder to unpack it to. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Kenny -- yes, that is what I meant with step #1.  Create a function which takes the input file name (foo_Jan-1-2012), does some string manipulation to determine the month and year, and then return it in MMYYYY format.  Make sense?

Comment: Do you have an example you can share?